# Early stopping using tensorflow tf.estimator ?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow v1.4. I want to use early stopping using the validation set with a patience of 5 epochs.

I have searched on the web and found out that there used to be a function called `ValidationMonitor` but it is depreciated now. So is there a way to achieve this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I have come across this function in tensorflow API. 
`tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`. tf version is r1.9.

Arguments:

- `monitor`: quantity to be monitored
- `min_delta`: minimum change in the monitored quantity to qualify as an improvement, i.e. an absolute change of less than min_delta, will count as no improvement.
- `patience`: number of epochs with no improvement after which training
  will be stopped.
- `verbose`: verbosity mode.
- `mode`: one of {`auto`, `min`, `max`}. In `min` mode, training will stop when
  the quantity monitored has stopped decreasing; in `max` mode it will
  stop when the quantity monitored has stopped increasing; in `auto`
  mode, the direction is automatically inferred from the name of the
  monitored quantity.

Comment: Can it be used in combination with estimators?

Comment: As far as I know, it can't be used with estimator. `tf.keras` is `Keras API` that can be used in tensorflow. This answer solved my problem but it can not be used with estimators.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good way of doing this, unfortunately. One method to consider is to save checkpoints quite often during training, and then later iterate over them and evaluating them. Then you can discard the checkpoints that does not have the best eval performance. This doesn't help you in saving time during training, but at least the resulting model you are left with is an early stopping model.

Comment: Thank you, for  the answer :) . What you suggested is an obvious solution, I'm using it right now. It would be nice to save the training time.